# When registering on a site through disqus also register this user own my own database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, disqus

So to be honest the title says what I'm after. I've searched and tried (nothing worth posting)

Has anybody ever tried to do this themselves?

Thanks in advance if anybody has thought about this.

Comment: This site pertains to answering questions in a Q&A form. You have to post code and tell us what you have tried so far. There are tons of documentation on the web and i'm use Disqus has a developper doc to get started. http://docs.disqus.com/developers/

Comment: aww bummer, my mistake i'm tempted to try and delete this question from embarrassment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to get this you will either need to grab out the details via JS with when the post is activated... but this is almost impossible.

So the best answer is to pay discus for their ultimate package and then they offer it to you via their api.